# Swift 2 : Try/Catch a non-throwing function

Tags: swift, try-catch, swift2

I'm refactoring a Obj-c class where there was a `@try/@catch` block around `removeObserver:`.

Doing the same thing in swift triggers a warning since `removeObserver` might fail (when there is no observer) but it doesn't throw any errors.

Any idea how I could achieve the same behaviour ?

edit : My code :

```
try {  
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "LineDisplayChanged")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `func removeObserver(_ anObserver: NSObject,forKeyPath keyPath: String)` you are calling is from the `NSKeyValueObserving` protocol and does not throws any exceptions.

Also, note that in Swift 2 the syntax for exception(that are actually ErrorType enum subclasses) has changed and is now something like this:

```
do{
   try functionThrowingExceptions()

}catch ErrorTypeSubclassEnum.Value {
   // Do something
}catch ErrorType {
   // Do something, catches everything else
}
```

See [this post](https://www.uraimo.com/2015/11/03/error-handling-from-objective-c-to-swift-2-and-back/) for more info.

Note: I'm using KVO with the latest beta of XCode7, doing a `self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "path")` does not trigger any error/warning.

Answer (score 0):

To remove warning just remove `try { }`. `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` is throwing an exception and not an error. And you cannot catch exceptions in Swift so make sure you call this method only if you observing it otherwise it will crash and there is no way around it in Swift.

You could write a category in Objective-C that wraps this call and capture the exception and returns an error instead.

Comment: The warning : `No call to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression`. Not really important, but I don't like warnings in my code :)